# Node.js Express 4 intercept failed static route

Tags: node.js, express, static, routes, middleware

I'm building a web site requiring a secure zone protected by a username/password (form authentication).

Here is the structure :

```
  - Project folder
      |- lib
         |- file and sub folders
      |- public
         |- fonts
             |- File and sub folders
         |- images
             |- File and sub folders
         |- javascript
             |- File and sub folders
         |- stylesheets
             |- File and sub folders
         |- Some file at root of public folder
      |- routes
         |- login.js
         |- home.js
         |- some others files...
      |- views
         |- layout
             |- File and sub folders
         |- Some file at root of views folder
```

Now I don't want to protect any file in the public folder, all of thoses are only static file, they can be serve directly.

I want to protect the secure zone, so all routes to views except the one going to login controller.

Here is what I've done so far :

```
// ...
var express = require('express');
var expressApp = express();
expressApp.set('port', httpPort);
expressApp.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
expressApp.set('view engine', 'ejs');
expressApp.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/images/favicon.ico'));
expressApp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// If static file has not been found, then 
// issue a 404 response and stop routing here
expressApp.get(['/public', '/public/*'], function (req, res) {
    res.send(404, 'Resource not found !');
});

// Configure a middleware that expose request object in the scoped EJS view
expressApp.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.request = req;
    next();
});

// Test if the user is authenticated before routing it 
// to any page other then login
var loginPage = require("./routes/login");
expressApp.use(["/login", "/login/*"], loginPage);
var ensureUserAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.user) {

      // Redirect to login page 
    }
    else {

        // Evaluate next route
        next();
    }
};

// Configure remaining routes
expressApp.use("/", ensureUserAuthenticated, require("./routes/index"));
expressApp.use("/home", ensureUserAuthenticated, require("./routes/home"));
expressApp.use("/settings-fan-settings", ensureUserAuthenticated, require("./routes/settings-fan-settings"));
expressApp.use("/settings-fan-settings-edit", ensureUserAuthenticated, require("./routes/settings-fan-settings-edit"));

// Route resource not found
expressApp.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).send('404 - Page Not Found !');
});
```

The problem is that If I'm pointing to a resource (static) that does not exists (ex : "/javascripts/foo.js", all middleware are trying to find the file until the last one returning the message "Page Not Found".

I've also tried the next solution but I get the same problem. This is the "**Page Not Found**" middleware that respond to the 404, not the one replying "**Resource Not Found**".

```
expressApp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
var staticFileResourceNotFound = function (req, res) {
    res.send(404, 'Resource not found !');
};
expressApp.get('/public', staticFileResourceNotFound);
expressApp.get('/public*', staticFileResourceNotFound);
 ...
expressApp.use("/", ensureUserAuthenticated, require("./routes/index"));
...

expressApp.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).send('404 - Page Not Found !');
});
```

Why the middleware having the message "Resource Not Found" is not triggered ? I put a breakpoint but it never reach.

I've tried many thing but I'm out of idea now.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The request "/javascript/foo.js" does not match the route

```
expressApp.get(['/public', '/public/*'], ...
```

You would need to define the path to the javascript files as something like

```
"/public/javascript/foo.js"
```

and change your route to remove the array of paths (no longer supported for app.VERB in Express 4.0)

```
expressApp.get('/public', handleRequestFunction());
expressApp.get('/public*', handleRequestFunction());
```

Comment: How can I match with all file/folder in public route ? I mean at root or subfolder of public folder but not in parent of public folder ?

Comment: The way I handle 404s is to put an app.use as the second to last command (the last being the error handler) that renders the 404 page.  This way, any routes not matched by the static file router or any other routers I define is just 404'ed

Comment: I understand, but this is not exactly my problem.

If I'm asking for a file in the public folder (static file) and its not found, I WANT immediately emit a 404 error. I DON'T WANT to evaluate next route until the last one. Because between the static route and the last one there are my SECURE ZONE route that evaluate if user is authenticated and return a 301 redirect instead of a 404.

Comment: Apparently, you cannot pass an array of paths into app.VERB (as of ver 4.0).  I have updated the answer to show what you should do instead.

Comment: I've updated the topic, I tried your solution but I got the same problem :(

Comment: My guess is the regex to match the path is not working somehow.  Can you try other paths, like "/public/missing.js" or "/publicmissing.js" and see if the route picks it up.  Btw, I still think you can move the 404 route handler to the bottom of the route stack because your "secure zone" routes should not be designed to redirect every request (one of the security advantages of the node web server is that it only responds to explicitly declared routes).  If your app functionality allows you to modify the way you are handling routes then your problem goes away.